# clickhouse moving average betwween partitions

Tags: window-functions, clickhouse, moving-average

how to calculate moving average betwween partitions in clickhouse.

for window_functions

set allow_experimental_window_functions = 1;

1、create table

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb (t DateTime, v Float32) ENGINE=MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(t) ORDER BY t;
```

(need partition by monthly)

2、insert values

```sql
INSERT INTO tb (t, v) VALUES ('2021-07-31 23:00:00', 5.0),
('2021-07-31 22:00:00', 4.0), ('2021-07-31 21:00:00', 3.0),
('2021-07-31 20:00:00', 2.0), ('2021-07-31 19:00:00', 1.0);
```

3、calculate moving average in materialized view

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS mv_tb ENGINE=MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(t)
ORDER BY t
POPULATE
AS SELECT t, v, avg(v) OVER w AS ma
FROM tb
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY t ASC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

4、query materialized view(everything is ok)
`select * from mv_tb;`

[image]

5、insert new datas

```sql
INSERT INTO tb (t, v) VALUES ('2021-08-01 01:00:00', 7.0),
('2021-08-01 00:00:00', 6.0);
```

6、query materialized view( ！！！wrong！！！)

`select * from mv_tb;`

[image]

Comment: Everything is expected here. 
1) Materialized Views with AVG require  states / AggregatingMergeTree engine. 2) it's impossible to use Window functions in Materialized views like you want. https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: Mat.View is an insert trigger it never reads the source table + it never reads own table.

Comment: thans you. Is there another way to do what I want?